# ClientProtocolException in httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler) after trying to remove GCM service

Tags: android, http-post, google-cloud-messaging

I have this code:

```
public void login(View view)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {
            try {
                usuario = txtUser.getText().toString();
                clave = txtPassword.getText().toString();
                Log.i("User", usuario);
                Log.i("Password", clave);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myurl.com/myapp/controller/_login.php");

                Log.i("Step", "2");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                Log.i("Step", "3");
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", usuario));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clave", clave));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                Log.i("Step", "4");
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
                Log.i("Step", "5");
                String respuesta = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                Log.v("Respuesta", respuesta);
                threadMsg(respuesta);
            } 
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.v("Error", "Error 1 ");
                mostrarToast("FAIL");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v("Error", "Error 2");
                mostrarToast("FAIL");
            }
        }        
}
```

And the manifiest permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This code worked until yesterday, but I was experimenting with GCM. I tried to remove the GCM dependencies, but now this app fails in http.execute.

I have a backup, but the backup fails in the same point now. And it keeps trying registering in GCM, despite I already remove the code that makes this registration and every related service.

How can I make this code work again? Why does my app keep registering in GCM?

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace.

Comment: I am a ***** noob. I spent hours in this problem and finally solved it restarting the phone.